# Do we ever see a 23rd Century Starfleet Officer with facial hair?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I recall that in the beginning of *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*, McCoy beams aboard the ship with a fabulous beard.  The next time we see him though, he's shaved it off.  That got me to thinking that I couldn't remember any instance of a Starfleet Officer from the 23rd Century with facial hair.  The 24th century, yes (Riker is the first that springs to mind), but not the 23rd century (*TOS* era).  So, my question is: **do we ever see a 23rd Century Starfleet Officer with facial hair?**. Note, I'm interested in **intentional** facial hair i.e. I won't accept the occasional 5 O'Clock shadow which has grown simply because they didn't get the chance to shave - I'm looking for facial hair which was clearly intended.

Comment: Before you downvote this or my answer, please bear in mind that I remembered Captain Bateson *after* I posted this question.  Also bear in mind that should someone find an instance from *TOS* or the *TMP* era, then that will be accepted.

Comment: Beards or *any* facial hair?

Comment: Great, now I have to watch TOS all over again ...

Comment: Cupcake, from the reboot and Into Darkness. Does he count - being from the JJ-verse?

Comment: Out of universe, it's a product of the times - this was the 60's, when men were expected to be smooth-shaven.  The hippy-movement challenged that, but it's likely the television networks would have balked at portraying any of that sort of thing on screen.  You'll be hard-pressed to find much facial hair on any contemporary shows from that era.  (By the 70's of course, this had completely changed - it's harder to find men *without* beards in the 70's.)

Comment: @steenbergh good point but I was thinking of the prime universe I'm afraid!  I'll clarify the question accordingly

Comment: I've never seen a 23rd century Starfleet Officer without facial hair.

Comment: @MajorStackings - Well indeed. [Kirk with Facial hair](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nIodz.jpg)

Comment: @Richard +1: I guess I should have said (aside from a couple of months somewhere along the way) that I haven't watched TV without facial hair since the late '70's.

Comment: [Sideburns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideburns) — common on men in *TOS* — are facial hair.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### TV Canon

We have **Captain Chandra** from TOS: Court Martial

[image]

And in the same vein as @N_Soong's answer, we do see two Starfleet Officers in the 23rd Century (courtesy of the episode DS9: [Trials and Tribble-ations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trials_and_Tribble-ations)) sporting facial hair; **Captain Sisko** and **Lt Cmdr Worf.**

[image]

Obviously Worf is a bit of a push (he's in disguise) but Sisko meets Kirk and **doesn't get shouted at for being out of uniform** for having a beard, suggesting that regulations merely require a beard to be tidy, rather than entirely absent

We also see **Lieutenant Kyle** (who seems to get more hair as he rises in rank - see below) as well as [Captain **O'Shea**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/O%27Shea) wearing a full beard in ST: The Animated Series.

[image: ![enter image description here]

### Film Canon

**Lieutenant Scott** sports some fine facial fuzz in ST:TMP

[image]

**Captain Terrell** and **Commander Kyle** in ST:II

[image]

**Captain Styles** and an **unnamed Engineering Crewman** in ST:III

[image]

An **unnamed Efrosian helmsman** and two **unnamed Caitan Admirals** in ST:IV

[image]

**Yeoman Burke, Colonel West, Lt Cmrd Valtane, Lt Cmdr Lojur**, an **unnamed Galley Officer** and **two unnamed Starfleet Admirals** in ST:VI

[image]

And here we can see **various unnamed Starfleet Officer cadets** in ST:TMP

[image]

Comment: Superior searching skills.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I have wasted a very considerable amount of time on this answer. I'm actually a little ashamed of myself :-)

Comment: And we have a winner.

Comment: I don't think we can get a much more comprehensive answer than this one; great work!

Comment: Glad you worked in a couple of the requisite "this guy"s. :)

Comment: Just letting you know I have set your first picture of an arrow pointing at Captain Chandra as my desktop background.

Comment: @xdhmoore - Has his glorious moustache inspired you to grow one of your own? :-{)

Comment: @Richard I could never match the genius of his sublety. As my friend James used to say, "Absence is the highest form of presence".

Answer (score 39):

Captain Krasnovsky ([**Court Martial**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Court_Martial_(episode)) - TOS S1Ep14)

[image]

played by [Bart Conrad](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bart_Conrad)

**Fleet Admiral Harry Morrow**

[image: Fleet Admiral Harry Morrow]

Per [**Memory Alpha**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Morrow)

> Harry Morrow was a Starfleet Fleet Admiral who served as Commander, Starfleet in 2285.
>
> Admiral Morrow was portrayed by Robert Hooks in Star Trek III - The Search for Spock.

If we count fur as hair

**Lt M'Ress**

[image: Lt M'Ress - ST:Animated]

[image]

Another Caitian (thanks to Richard)

[image]

Unnamed Senior Officer (top left)

Comment: @Paulie_D lol M'Ress

Comment: I love unnamed background senior officer. He's my favourite character in that film

Comment: I love all his work.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Especially that thing he's in.

Comment: What, the one where he did that  thing he's famous for?

Comment: @Paulie_D - No, not that one. I didn't like him in that.

Comment: Yeah, he's a bit typecast now.

Comment: If you're listing Caitans, you might want to add [this guy](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/7/7d/Caitian-brown.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20051124061813&path-prefix=en) from ST:VI.

Comment: Nice job finding an example from TOS! I think your answer should be the winner because of that, even though the other answers are good.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - The OP mentioned TOS **or TMP-era** in their comments.

Comment: @Richard - True, but given that N_Soong said Captain Morgan Bateson would be overridden by TOS or TMP, I figured there was probably a preference for earlier examples over later ones, so TOS would trump TMP. This may not have been the intent though, perhaps N_Soong can comment.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Not the only find :-P

Comment: @Richard - Nice one. now that you both have a mustachio'd character from TOS, I'd vote for your answer since it's more extensive.

Comment: @Richard "So far" = at the time of writing. ...at at least as of the time when I scrolled below your answer. ;)

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Interesting that both of the TOS characters referenced in these two answers were from the same episode...

Answer (score 26):

I wrote this question and only now have I remembered one: **[Captain Morgan Bateson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Morgan_Bateson) of the *USS Bozeman*** who we see in *TNG* 'Cause and Effect'

[image: Captain Bateson]

Although he technically *is* a 23rd Century Starfleet Officer, in the spirit of the original question, this would be overridden by a TOS- or TMP-era instance.

Answer (score 5):

Who can forget [Spock from the mirror universe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock_%28mirror%29)...

[image: He had a beard.]

Comment: He is not a Starfleet officer. He is an officer of the [Terran Empire](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Terran_Empire)

Comment: @Richard, at least according to Memory-Alpha, he was an officer in the Imperial version of  [Starfleet](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_(mirror)).