# In-universe and out-of-universe meaning behind droid names?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, names, droids

What are the in-universe *and* out-of-universe meanings behind the names droids are given?

The out-of-universe origin of R2-D2 ("Reel 2 - Dialogue 2") is widely known, but what about in-universe?

There a question about the out-of-universe meaning of C-3PO as @Richard points out, but what about in-universe?

My question is different because I'm looking for a long list of in and out-of-universe info on the many droids of *Star Wars*.

- IG-88
- TC-14
- C1-1OP
- 4-LOM
- R4
- 8T-88

Etc.

**What do they all stand for?**

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55876/what-is-the-origin-or-significance-of-c-3pos-name

Comment: They aren't names, they're model numbers. The letters indicate they type, the numbers seem to indicate the series. Like a T-1000 or an HK-1

Comment: It looks like the question @Richard linked is the out of universe version,  so this question may do better focusing on the in universe reason.

Comment: There's also 0B1KN0B.

Comment: "List away, people!". Dupe or not, what you're asking for is too broad.

Comment: @phantom42 How is it too broad? There are plenty of questions asking for lists, I'm confused.

Comment: Some list questions are acceptable. However, you're asking for a long unbounded list. This leads to partial answers that aren't objectively "right" or "wrong", making questions like this a poor fit for the site. Even if you were to specify that you're just looking for info on the specific six you mentioned, it would still be too broad as it's unlikely anyone will find sufficient information on all six, leading to the same issue.

Comment: A linked question #1 is wrong. I'll  try to reopen and reclose

Comment: @phantom42 "Even if you were to specify that you're just looking for info on the specific six you mentioned, it would still be too broad" I'm fine if that's true, but if that's true then what's wrong with my question that _isn't_ wrong with these ones: [1](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110173/do-we-ever-see-a-23rd-century-starfleet-officer-with-facial-hair), [2](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/star-wars-referencing-star-trek-or-vice-versa), [3](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55408/novels-set-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe)

Comment: "Any/examples" questions have for some reason, been made exempt from the list rules. I still disagree with it. The ST/SW question is very old, before the list stuff really got defined. The novels one is both an "any", and will have a very limited scope of answers that doesn't require a lot of additional information. If you want more information, drop into chat or ask on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Star Wars Insider #58 (Page 97), it is noted that the in-universe robot names are fragments (shorter versions) of longer serial numbers.

The Q&As are done by Pablo Hidalgo, Internet Content Provider for starwars.com.

[image]